# Change function stops working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have this simple change function:

```
function checkradio() {
    $("input.checkbox_check").change(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            console.log('checked');
            var here = $(this).attr("id");

            console.log(here);
            $('.' + here).addClass("line_marked");
            $('.' + here).removeClass("hide");
            $('.' + here).removeClass("inactive");
        } 
        else {
            var here = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(here);

            $('.' + here).removeClass("line_marked");
            $('.' + here).addClass("inactive");
            $('.' + here).addClass("hide");

            console.log(here);
            console.log('not checked');
        }
    });
}
```

It checks to see if a number of checkboxes are checked, takes the id of the checked checkbox and then adds and removes a couple of css classes to a line graph (built in d3) with the corresponding class of the id.

The action is dependant of wheter the checkbox is checked or not.

This works perfectly in all browsers (not ie8), except for Chrome. In chrome it works fine as long as I continue to click the checkboxes. But if I wait around 40 seconds with the window open, the change function stops working. I then have to click and unclick the checkbox before it starts working again.

I get no error message in the console.

Comment: what do you see in your console o/p?

Comment: where are you calling `checkradio()` from? is it possible that you are calling it multiple times say from the callback of an ajax function or within a loop?

Comment: Good question, I do get the console.log messages. So the function fires, but the css classes in question are not added/removed.

Comment: No, it is called like this checkradio(); within a $(function() { })

Comment: seems like you want class here $('.' + here).but you are using id `$(this).attr("id");`

Comment: by the looks of it you have some other bit of code that is removing the classes from the elements. Are you able to check the elements after 40 seconds and see whether the class has changed?

Comment: @captain Hmm, I think this is correct. I do want the id of the checkbox, but I want to alter the line with the same class.

Comment: you want to alter all the elements that have the class that is the same as the id of the checkbox you changed?

Comment: @DGS Not sure I understand "some other code". There's no other function. The addClass and removeClass takes care of the adding/removing.

Comment: @DGS Yes, there's only one element with the same class as id, but yes.

Comment: I mean some other code that exists in your application that you have not posted here. Is there any other place in your code that you call `addClass` or `removeClass`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37881/discussion-between-dgs-and-user1009453)